# PHP Assigning Concatenated Methods in a Class Property

Tags: php, concatenation

Why can't I assign a value in a class property like this? First the error I am getting:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\wamp\www\site\people.php on line 8

The code:

```
<?php

$person = new People;
echo $person->getPersonInfo();

class People
{
private $person_info = $this->getName . ' ' . $this->getGender . ' and ' . $this->getAge() . '.';
private $person = array(
'name' => 'Sarah',
'gender' => 'female',
'age' => 21
);

public function __construct()
{
    echo 'Class is created.' . '<br>';
}

public function getName()
{
    return $this->person['name'];
}

public function getGender()
{
    return $this->person['gender'];
}

public function getAge()
{
    return $this->person['age'];
}

public function getPersonInfo()
{
    return $this->person_info;
}
}
```

Comment: Because http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php _This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated._ **Build it in the constructor.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set dynamic values in the class properties like that; they have to be constant values. You have to make such assignments in the constructor

```
// NO
private $person_info = $this->getName . ' ' . $this->getGender . ' and ' . $this->getAge() . '.';

// YES
public function __construct() {
  $this->person_info = $this->getName . ' ' . $this->getGender . ' and ' . $this->getAge() . '.';
}
```

But what you actually mean is this

```
// you're calling get methods, not properties
// make sure to use $this->getName(), not $this->getName
public function __construct() {
  $this->person_info = $this->getName() . ' ' . $this->getGender() . ' and ' . $this->getAge() . '.';
}
```

But actually all of your code is bad

```
// This makes no sense to have as a constant property in a class
private $person = array(
  'name' => 'Sarah',
  'gender' => 'female',
  'age' => 21
);
```

This class makes way more sense for your purposes

```
class Person { 

  // container for your info object
  private $info = [];

  // make info a parameter for your constructor
  public function __construct(array $info = []) {
    $this->info = $info;
  }

  // use PHP magic method __get to fetch values from info array
  public function __get(string $attr) {
    return array_key_exists($attr, $this->info)
      ? $this->info[$attr]
      : null;
  }

  // use PHP magic method __set to set values in the info array
  public function __set(string $attr, $value) {
    $this->info[$attr] = $value;
  }

  // single method to fetch the entire info object
  public function getInfo() {
    return $this->info;
  }
}
```

Simple. Let's see how it works now

```
$p = new Person([
  'name' => 'Sarah',
  'gender' => 'female',
  'age' => 21
]);

echo $p->name, PHP_EOL;
// Sarah

echo $p->gender, PHP_EOL;
// female

echo $p->age, PHP_EOL;
// 21

echo json_encode($p->getInfo()), PHP_EOL;
// {"name":"Sarah","gender":"female","age":21}
```

Because the `$info` array is a parameter now, you can easily create Person objects with other data

```
$q = new Person([
  'name' => 'Joey',
  'gender' => 'male',
  'age' => 15
]);

echo $q->name, PHP_EOL;
// Joey

echo $q->gender, PHP_EOL;
// male

echo $q->age, PHP_EOL;
// 15

echo json_encode($q->getInfo()), PHP_EOL;
// {"name":"Joey","gender":"male","age":15}
```

Comment: I really appreciate all the new knowledge. There will be a lot more to learn now, so thank you. Back to the topic, in the comment it says, "This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated
at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated." That's too much english to me right now.